# Alertify in a asp.net c# page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, alertify

sorry if my english is poor.

I've a question, i think that the problem is my poor knowledge of javascript but.. i know that you can help me about this.

i've a page with an imagebutton, i use this for delete data and i need a confirmation dialog box. Alertify is pretty, i use altertify alert in server side like this:

```
string myScript2 = "alertify.error('message.')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), 
                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), myScript2, true);
return;
```

and work fine!

but i don't understand how to use alertify.confirm.

for example i've used

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/alertify.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include the core styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/alertify.core.css" />
    <!-- include a theme, can be included into the core instead of 2 separate files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/alertify.default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btElimina").on('click', function () {
            alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog", function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    alertify.success("You've clicked OK");
                } else {
                    alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

but nothing to do...i can't use onclientclick because alertify is a non-blocking instead a modal windows... 
can you help me to understand? not to write code for me, but, to understand and make me viable
thank you

Henry

Answer (score 1):

Replace `alertify.success("You've clicked OK");` with `return true;`
 and `alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");` with `return false;`

Also change this:

```
$("#btElimina").on('click', function () {
```

to this:

```
$("#<%=btElimina.ClientID%>").on('click', return function () {
```

Comment: Thank you, now i have correct the code. Now when i click the imagebutton, this button `<asp:ImageButton ID="btElimina" 
                ImageUrl="~/images/Elimina.png" runat="server" 
                      />` the page refresh but doesn't do nothing. i don't see a confirm dialog box. But thank you, i understand with you answer that i can take a response like onclientclick

Comment: please confirm what is the id of imagebutton on render in html. I think it will not be btElimina. check it.

Comment: yes, in this post i write btElimina because the real name on render in html is long. and is  `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btElimina`

Comment: yes,therefore your js code is not firing. see the update answer

Comment: yes, and i dont understand why! i have some js code in this page and work fine! for example, open page in popup dialog ecc..

Comment: your click function is getting binded to nothing because there is no btElimina. all asp control get different id on getting rendered so you will have to use that id instead of serverid.

Comment: yes, in this post i write `btElimina` but in code i use `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btElimina` but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it is working:

My button is :

```
<asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Çıkış" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="Image/Exit.png" runat="server"  OnClick="btnLogout_Click" />
```

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ImageButton1").on('click', function () {
        alertify.confirm("This is a confirm dialog", function (e) {
            if (e) {
                alertify.success("You've clicked OK");

                __doPostBack("<%=ImageButton1.UniqueID%>", "");
            } else {
                alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Here when i clicked "cancel" button returns false and doing nothing but when you clicked ok button  i am doing postback for related button and you can write your own code in server side

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the last comment below as I don't have 50 reputation, so I'm posting an answer simply to elaborate on Ratna's answer.

As per Ratna's answer, you should use server tags to refer to ASP.Net controls (controls with runat="server") to ensure that you get the control regardless of what ASP.Net renames the control to.

So to reiterate Ratna's answer:

Instead of

```
$('#btElimina').on(..
```

use

```
$('#<%= btElimina.ClientID %>').on(..
```

to make sure that you get the correct clientside control id in your jQuery script.